# How to place links?

Tags: css

I have this page below:

http://www.tirengarfio.com/rs2/web/borrar.php

What should i do to put the link in the first line but on the right of the page?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**CSS float property**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_float.asp):

```
<a href="#" style="float: right;">Link</a>
<h1 style="display: inline;">Juan Garcia Granados</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Anyway I can't find float attribute here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: It's a CSS property, not an HTML attribute. Also, there is a link directly to the CSS float property documentation above.